# How do I resolve this linphone $ make error?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, cmake, linphone

I was able to successfully run the `prepare.py` script in top directory without errors.

However when I run the `$ make` command, I get the error bellow.

Can anybody save me from this torment.

```
[ 33%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/msamr.dir/amrnb.c.o
/home/pnwoke/linphone-android/submodules/msamr/src/amrnb.c:31:10: fatal error: 
      'amrnb/interf_dec.h' file not found
#include <amrnb/interf_dec.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
src/CMakeFiles/msamr.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/msamr.dir/amrnb.c.o' failed
make[6]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/msamr.dir/amrnb.c.o] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/pnwoke/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/Build/msamr'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/msamr.dir/all' failed
make[5]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/msamr.dir/all] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pnwoke/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/Build/msamr'
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pnwoke/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/Build/msamr'
CMakeFiles/EP_msamr.dir/build.make:111: recipe for target '/home/pnwoke/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/Stamp/EP_msamr/EP_msamr-build' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/pnwoke/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/Stamp/EP_msamr/EP_msamr-build] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pnwoke/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/cmake'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:571: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/EP_msamr.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/EP_msamr.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pnwoke/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/cmake'
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pnwoke/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/cmake'
Makefile:148: recipe for target 'arm-build' failed
make: *** [arm-build] Error 2
```

Comment: Output of VERBOSE=yes, Where is the header file the compiler is looking for located?

Comment: DId you install opencore-amr? Also tells us a bit about environment

Comment: I am quite new to linphone, so i am not familiar with the header file... i only followed the steps indicated [here](http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html)

Comment: I try configuring linphone on windows but i realized that most of its dependencies are easier setting up on a linux environment. so i switch to my ubuntu14

Comment: I installed `opencore-amr` but still getting thesame error for `$ make`

Comment: same here :( how did you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the error occurred because my linker wasn't picking the header file *interf_dec.h*

So i edited this file */home/pnwoke/linphone-android/submodules/msamr/src/amrnb.c--->line:31:10* by putting the absolute directory of the header file (eg: /home/pnwoke/linphone-android/submodules/msamr/src/interf_dec.h)

[image]

[image]

So if you don't see the header file in that directory, don't panic. Lol. Just search the entire linphone folder and copy from wherever it is to the directory of *amrnb.c*

Do the same to any error that complains of missing header file